# SQL filter condition: Find IDs who only have expired offers

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[image]

If I want to get IDs of those whose offer expired:

```sql
select ID card 
from table 
where offer expiry date < current date
```

Result brings IDs : 1(as 'a' is expired) , 2  (as both 'a','b' is expired)

If I want to get IDs of those who "only" have expired offers, how should I write?
Result should bring "only" ID : 2 as all his offers are expired.
TIA

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max()`:

```
select id_card
from t
group by id_main
having max(expiry_date) < current_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following thing:-

1. find date difference between expire_date and current_date
2. Sum the DATEDIFF values with GROUP of ID_Card
3. And negative result means all date are expire for that particular ID_Card

```
SELECT ID_Card FROM MAIN
GROUP BY ID_Card
HAVING (COUNT(ID_Card) = COUNT( CASE WHEN datediff(day,offer_expire_date, current_date)<0 THEN 1 END))
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried, but it is still pulling IDs with the combination of active and expired offers. As described in the question, I am looking for IDs who "only" have expired offers.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my query. Please check now.